# RedisTemplate `execute` type mismatch

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis

```
    @Resource
    private StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;

    @Resource
    private RedisTemplate defaultRedisTemplate;



RedisScript<Boolean> redisScript = new DefaultRedisScript(Test, Boolean.class);

  // this line is OK, stringRedisTemplate.execute returns boolean
  boolean result1 = stringRedisTemplate.execute(redisScript, Arrays.asList(key), value);
  
  // line blow indicates type mismatch, defaultRedisTemplate.execute returns Object
  boolean result2 = defaultRedisTemplate.execute(redisScript, Arrays.asList(key), value);
```

why the `defaultRedisTemplate.execute`'s return Type is Object instead of boolean?

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface RedisOperations<K,V> {
    public <T> T execute(RedisScript<T> script, List<K> keys, Object... args)
}

public class StringRedisTemplate extends RedisTemplate<String,String> {}
```

This is expected compile time behavior when the generic method is invoked from raw type class.

On the other [`StringRedisTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/StringRedisTemplate.html) is a pseudo type because of its super class type parameters `RedisTemplate`  as defined above.

This is the reason why the compilation succeeds for string redis template variant.

If you were to pass the generic variant the code will compile fine.

```
@Resource
private RedisTemplate<String, Object> defaultRedisTemplate;
```